# IIS 8.5 "You do not have permission to view this page."

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

About two days ago I was able to access every page on my site and look into every directory but for some bizarre reason that has now changed and I am unable to access a certain directory.

I have given both IUSRS and IIS_IUSRS full access to the directory but I am still unable to gain access.

I am using IIS 8.5 and I have Anonymous Authentication enabled.

Has anybody encountered this issue before or know how to fix such an issue?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to access the directory? If you're trying to browse to the directory's URL, then you need to make sure directory browsing is turned on for that directory, otherwise you get a 403. Find the directory in IIS and after clicking it in the left pane there should be a directory browsing icon in the right pane.

Comment: Thank you very much @TedSales . I done goof'ed and didn't enable Directory Browsing. Thank you!

Comment: What did you to solve it